# How to use colors to distinguish between bordering features in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I have a lot of data that involves connecting line segment features, and they already have color-coded categories based on the type of segment. Is there away to have touching features shaded differently or distinguished in some other way so that it's more obvious where one ends and the other starts? I don't know if QGIS has an existing option for this or if there is a plugin that does this.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Answer (score 3):

There is a tool `Topological coloring`, however only for polygons, not lines. You could still use it:

1. Create a (small) buffer around your lines.
2. Apply `Menu Processing / Toolbox / Topological coloring` to the buffer: it will create a new attribute `color_id`.
3. Use Categorized styling and set the color to the field `color_id`.
4. Optional: you can join the `color_id` created on your buffer layer back to your original line layer with `Join attributes by location`

*The screenshot shows the solution using buffers: if they are small enough, they appear as lines:*

[image]